# Zend Form addDisplayGroup, setElementDecorators

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, decorator, zend-decorators

Hi I want to Design a Zend_form As following:

## Question:1

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
<div id="block">
<fieldset id="fieldblock">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input1">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input1">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input1">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input1">
</fieldset>
</div>
</form>
```

My Current OutPut:

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
<div id="block">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input1">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input2">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input3">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input4">
</div>
</form>
```

I am using the following Decrotives:

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(array('input1','input2','input3','input4'),
                                       'Date', array('order'     => 4,
                                                    'decorators' => array('FormElements',
                                                                        array('HtmlTag', 
                                                                            array('tag'     => 'div',
                                                                                 'class'    => 'block',
                                                                                 ),
                                                                             ),
                                                                          ),
                                                    )
                                );
```

How to Add Field Set to the setgroup?

## Question:2

Expected OOUTPUT:

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
<div id="block">
<fieldset id="fieldblock">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input1">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input1">
<div id="block2">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input1">
Lable: <input type="text" name="input1">
<div id="block2">
</fieldset>
</div>
</form>
```

IF I want to add "`addDisplayGroup`" inside Another Display Group, How Can I do it?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soon I will post the answer:

I refer the following three links and Solved my issue hope it will be useful for others.

[Ref Link 1](http://jamestombs.co.uk/2008-04-24/zend-adddisplaygroup-setting-the-legend/767)
http://jamestombs.co.uk/2008-04-24/zend-adddisplaygroup-setting-the-legend/767

[Ref Link 2:](http://jamestombs.co.uk/2008-04-24/zend-adddisplaygroup-setting-the-legend/767) http://jamestombs.co.uk/2008-04-24/zend-adddisplaygroup-setting-the-legend/767

[Ref Like 3:](http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/applying-decorators-to-all-elements-of-form-elements-at-once/) http://zendguru.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/applying-decorators-to-all-elements-of-form-elements-at-once/

This three links are very use full to understand the for decorative.

## Answer:1

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(array('input1','input2','input3','input4'),
                                       'Date', array('order'     => 4,
                                                    'decorators' => array('FormElements',
                                                                        array('HtmlTag', 'Fieldset'
                                                                            array('tag'     => 'div',
                                                                                 'class'    => 'block',
                                                                                 ),
                                                                             ),
                                                                          ),
                                                    )
                                );
```